# PDF Alignment issues when upgrading from fop-0.95 to fop-2.3

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0, xsl-fo, apache-fop

I'm new to the XSLT FO world and came across an issue. I have my XSLT that works well with the fop-0.95 processor and generates the PDF, but after I upgraded to fop-2.3, it left my first page blank and started the PDF body from the second page (my PDF has a header that appears fine on the first page).

I figured out where the issue was, and it was because I had the `margin-top` value set to 3 inches in the "fo:region-body" tag within the "fo:layout-master-set" (please see screenshot). I had to change the `margin-top` from 3 inches to 2.5 inches for the body of my PDF to appear like it was while using fop-0.95.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!--Designed and generated by Altova StyleVision Enterprise Edition 2013 (x64) - see http://www.altova.com/stylevision for more information.-->
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:altova="http://www.altova.com" xmlns:altovaext="http://www.altova.com/xslt-extensions" xmlns:clitype="clitype" xmlns:fn="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions" xmlns:iso4217="http://www.xbrl.org/2003/iso4217" xmlns:ix="http://www.xbrl.org/2008/inlineXBRL" xmlns:java="java" xmlns:link="http://www.xbrl.org/2003/linkbase" xmlns:sps="http://www.altova.com/StyleVision/user-xpath-functions" xmlns:xbrldi="http://xbrl.org/2006/xbrldi" xmlns:xbrli="http://www.xbrl.org/2003/instance" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format" xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" exclude-result-prefixes="altova altovaext clitype fn iso4217 ix java link sps xbrldi xbrli xlink xs xsi">
    <xsl:output version="1.0" method="xml" encoding="UTF-8" indent="no"/>
    <xsl:param name="SV_OutputFormat" select="'PDF'"/>
    <xsl:variable name="XML" select="/"/>
    <xsl:variable name="fo:layout-master-set">
        <fo:layout-master-set>
            <fo:simple-page-master master-name="page-master-0-even" margin-left="0.50in" margin-right="0.50in" page-height="11in" page-width="8.50in" margin-top="0.30in" margin-bottom="0.30in">
                <fo:region-body margin-top="0.45in" margin-bottom="0.45in" column-count="1" column-gap="0.50in"/>
                <fo:region-before region-name="even-page-header" overflow="hidden" extent="0.45in"/>
                <fo:region-after region-name="even-page-footer" overflow="hidden" extent="0.45in"/>
            </fo:simple-page-master>
            <fo:simple-page-master master-name="page-master-0-odd" margin-left="0.50in" margin-right="0.50in" page-height="11in" page-width="8.50in" margin-top="0.30in" margin-bottom="0.30in">
                <fo:region-body margin-top="0.45in" margin-bottom="0.45in" column-count="1" column-gap="0.50in"/>
                <fo:region-before region-name="odd-page-header" overflow="hidden" extent="0.45in"/>
                <fo:region-after region-name="odd-page-footer" overflow="hidden" extent="0.45in"/>
            </fo:simple-page-master>
            <fo:simple-page-master master-name="page-master-0-even-first" margin-left="0.50in" margin-right="0.50in" page-height="11in" page-width="8.50in" margin-top="0.30in" margin-bottom="0.30in">
                <fo:region-body margin-top="3in" margin-bottom="0.45in" column-count="1" column-gap="0.50in"/>
                <fo:region-before region-name="even-page-header-first" overflow="hidden" extent="3in"/>
                <fo:region-after region-name="even-page-footer" overflow="hidden" extent="0.45in"/>
            </fo:simple-page-master>
            <fo:simple-page-master master-name="page-master-0-odd-first" margin-left="0.50in" margin-right="0.50in" page-height="11in" page-width="8.50in" margin-top="0.30in" margin-bottom="0.30in">
                <fo:region-body margin-top="3in" margin-bottom="0.45in" column-count="1" column-gap="0.50in"/>
                <fo:region-before region-name="odd-page-header-first" overflow="hidden" extent="3in"/>
                <fo:region-after region-name="odd-page-footer" overflow="hidden" extent="0.45in"/>
            </fo:simple-page-master>
            <fo:page-sequence-master master-name="page-master-0">
                <fo:repeatable-page-master-alternatives>
                    <fo:conditional-page-master-reference master-reference="page-master-0-even-first" odd-or-even="even" page-position="first"/>
                    <fo:conditional-page-master-reference master-reference="page-master-0-odd-first" odd-or-even="odd" page-position="first"/>
                    <fo:conditional-page-master-reference master-reference="page-master-0-even" odd-or-even="even"/>
                    <fo:conditional-page-master-reference master-reference="page-master-0-odd" odd-or-even="odd"/>
                </fo:repeatable-page-master-alternatives>
            </fo:page-sequence-master>
        </fo:layout-master-set>
    </xsl:variable>
    <xsl:variable name="altova:nPxPerIn" select="96"/>
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <fo:root>
            <xsl:copy-of select="$fo:layout-master-set"/>
            <fo:declarations>
                <x:xmpmeta xmlns:x="adobe:ns:meta/">
                    <rdf:RDF xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#">
                        <rdf:Description rdf:about="" xmlns:xmp="http://ns.adobe.com/xap/1.0/">
                            <xmp:CreatorTool>Altova StyleVision Enterprise Edition 2013 (x64) (http://www.altova.com)</xmp:CreatorTool>
                        </rdf:Description>
                    </rdf:RDF>
                </x:xmpmeta>
            </fo:declarations>
            <fo:page-sequence force-page-count="no-force" master-reference="page-master-0" initial-page-number="auto" format="1">
                <fo:static-content flow-name="odd-page-header-first">
                    <fo:block-container overflow="hidden" display-align="before">
                        <fo:block>
                            <xsl:for-each select="$XML">
                                <xsl:for-each select="DOCUMENT">
                                    <xsl:for-each select="DATA">
                                        <xsl:for-each select="STRUCT">
                                            <xsl:for-each select="FIELD[FNAME=&apos;nfHeaderDtls&apos;]">
                                                <xsl:for-each select="STRUCT">
                                                    <fo:block-container font-family="Arial" font-size="10pt" width="7.490000in" height="3.000000in" overflow="hidden">
                                                        <fo:block-container absolute-position="absolute" font-family="Arial" font-size="9pt" height="1.21in" left="4.55in" top="1.75in" width="2.90in" overflow="hidden">
                                                            <fo:block>
                                                                <xsl:for-each select="FIELD[FNAME=&apos;Name&apos;]">
                                                                    <xsl:for-each select="VALUE">
                                                                        <xsl:variable name="value-of-template_1">
                                                                            <xsl:apply-templates/>
                                                                        </xsl:variable>
                                                                        <xsl:choose>
                                                                            <xsl:when test="contains(string($value-of-template_1),'&#x200B;')">
                                                                                <fo:block>
                                                                                    <xsl:copy-of select="$value-of-template_1"/>
                                                                                </fo:block>
                                                                            </xsl:when>
                                                                            <xsl:otherwise>
                                                                                <fo:inline>
                                                                                    <xsl:copy-of select="$value-of-template_1"/>
                                                                                </fo:inline>
                                                                            </xsl:otherwise>
                                                                        </xsl:choose>
                                                                    </xsl:for-each>
                                                                </xsl:for-each>
                                                                <fo:block/>
                                                            </fo:block>
                                                        </fo:block-container>
                                                    </fo:block-container>
                                                </xsl:for-each>
                                            </xsl:for-each>
                                        </xsl:for-each>
                                    </xsl:for-each>
                                </xsl:for-each>
                            </xsl:for-each>
                        </fo:block>
                    </fo:block-container>
                </fo:static-content>
                <fo:static-content flow-name="even-page-header-first">
                    <fo:block-container overflow="hidden" display-align="before">
                        <fo:block>
                            <xsl:for-each select="$XML">
                                <xsl:for-each select="DOCUMENT">
                                    <xsl:for-each select="DATA">
                                        <xsl:for-each select="STRUCT">
                                            <xsl:for-each select="FIELD[FNAME=&apos;nfHeaderDtls&apos;]">
                                                <xsl:for-each select="STRUCT">
                                                    <fo:block-container font-family="Arial" font-size="10pt" width="7.490000in" height="3.000000in" overflow="hidden">
                                                        <fo:block-container absolute-position="absolute" font-family="Arial" font-size="9pt" height="1.21in" left="4.55in" top="1.75in" width="2.90in" overflow="hidden">
                                                            <fo:block>
                                                                <xsl:for-each select="FIELD[FNAME=&apos;Name&apos;]">
                                                                    <xsl:for-each select="VALUE">
                                                                        <xsl:variable name="value-of-template_1">
                                                                            <xsl:apply-templates/>
                                                                        </xsl:variable>
                                                                        <xsl:choose>
                                                                            <xsl:when test="contains(string($value-of-template_1),'&#x200B;')">
                                                                                <fo:block>
                                                                                    <xsl:copy-of select="$value-of-template_1"/>
                                                                                </fo:block>
                                                                            </xsl:when>
                                                                            <xsl:otherwise>
                                                                                <fo:inline>
                                                                                    <xsl:copy-of select="$value-of-template_1"/>
                                                                                </fo:inline>
                                                                            </xsl:otherwise>
                                                                        </xsl:choose>
                                                                    </xsl:for-each>
                                                                </xsl:for-each>
                                                                <fo:block/>
                                                            </fo:block>
                                                        </fo:block-container>
                                                    </fo:block-container>
                                                </xsl:for-each>
                                            </xsl:for-each>
                                        </xsl:for-each>
                                    </xsl:for-each>
                                </xsl:for-each>
                            </xsl:for-each>
                        </fo:block>
                    </fo:block-container>
                </fo:static-content>
                <fo:static-content flow-name="odd-page-header">
                    <fo:block-container overflow="hidden" display-align="before">
                        <fo:block>
                            <xsl:for-each select="$XML">
                                <xsl:for-each select="DOCUMENT">
                                    <xsl:for-each select="DATA">
                                        <xsl:for-each select="STRUCT">
                                            <xsl:for-each select="FIELD[FNAME=&apos;nfHeaderDtls&apos;]">
                                                <xsl:for-each select="STRUCT">
                                                    <fo:block-container font-family="Arial" font-size="10pt" width="7.500000in" height="0.500000in" overflow="hidden">
                                                        <fo:block-container absolute-position="absolute" height="0.19in" left="0in" top="0in" width="2.78in" overflow="hidden">
                                                            <fo:block>
                                                                <fo:inline>
                                                                    <xsl:text>Identifier: </xsl:text>
                                                                </fo:inline>
                                                                <xsl:for-each select="FIELD[FNAME=&apos;caseReference&apos;]">
                                                                    <xsl:for-each select="VALUE">
                                                                        <xsl:variable name="value-of-template_27">
                                                                            <xsl:apply-templates/>
                                                                        </xsl:variable>
                                                                        <xsl:choose>
                                                                            <xsl:when test="contains(string($value-of-template_27),'&#x200B;')">
                                                                                <fo:block>
                                                                                    <xsl:copy-of select="$value-of-template_27"/>
                                                                                </fo:block>
                                                                            </xsl:when>
                                                                            <xsl:otherwise>
                                                                                <fo:inline>
                                                                                    <xsl:copy-of select="$value-of-template_27"/>
                                                                                </fo:inline>
                                                                            </xsl:otherwise>
                                                                        </xsl:choose>
                                                                    </xsl:for-each>
                                                                </xsl:for-each>
                                                            </fo:block>
                                                        </fo:block-container>
                                                    </fo:block-container>
                                                </xsl:for-each>
                                            </xsl:for-each>
                                        </xsl:for-each>
                                    </xsl:for-each>
                                </xsl:for-each>
                            </xsl:for-each>
                        </fo:block>
                    </fo:block-container>
                </fo:static-content>
                <fo:static-content flow-name="even-page-header">
                    <fo:block-container overflow="hidden" display-align="before">
                        <fo:block>
                            <xsl:for-each select="$XML">
                                <xsl:for-each select="DOCUMENT">
                                    <xsl:for-each select="DATA">
                                        <xsl:for-each select="STRUCT">
                                            <xsl:for-each select="FIELD[FNAME=&apos;nfHeaderDtls&apos;]">
                                                <xsl:for-each select="STRUCT">
                                                    <fo:block-container font-family="Arial" font-size="10pt" width="7.500000in" height="0.500000in" overflow="hidden">
                                                        <fo:block-container absolute-position="absolute" height="0.19in" left="0in" top="0in" width="2.78in" overflow="hidden">
                                                            <fo:block>
                                                                <fo:inline>
                                                                    <xsl:text>Identifier: </xsl:text>
                                                                </fo:inline>
                                                                <xsl:for-each select="FIELD[FNAME=&apos;caseReference&apos;]">
                                                                    <xsl:for-each select="VALUE">
                                                                        <xsl:variable name="value-of-template_27">
                                                                            <xsl:apply-templates/>
                                                                        </xsl:variable>
                                                                        <xsl:choose>
                                                                            <xsl:when test="contains(string($value-of-template_27),'&#x200B;')">
                                                                                <fo:block>
                                                                                    <xsl:copy-of select="$value-of-template_27"/>
                                                                                </fo:block>
                                                                            </xsl:when>
                                                                            <xsl:otherwise>
                                                                                <fo:inline>
                                                                                    <xsl:copy-of select="$value-of-template_27"/>
                                                                                </fo:inline>
                                                                            </xsl:otherwise>
                                                                        </xsl:choose>
                                                                    </xsl:for-each>
                                                                </xsl:for-each>
                                                            </fo:block>
                                                        </fo:block-container>
                                                    </fo:block-container>
                                                </xsl:for-each>
                                            </xsl:for-each>
                                        </xsl:for-each>
                                    </xsl:for-each>
                                </xsl:for-each>
                            </xsl:for-each>
                        </fo:block>
                    </fo:block-container>
                </fo:static-content>
                <fo:static-content flow-name="odd-page-footer">
                    <fo:block-container height="0.45in" overflow="hidden" display-align="after">
                        <fo:block>
                            <fo:block-container font-family="Arial" font-size="10pt" width="7.490000in" height="0.500000in" overflow="hidden">
                                <fo:block-container absolute-position="absolute" height="0.40in" left="0in" top="0in" width="4.04in" overflow="hidden">
                                    <fo:block>
                                        <fo:inline>
                                            <xsl:text>My Test Form</xsl:text>
                                        </fo:inline>
                                        <fo:block/>
                                        <fo:inline>
                                            <xsl:text>Test Text</xsl:text>
                                        </fo:inline>
                                    </fo:block>
                                </fo:block-container>
                                <fo:block-container absolute-position="absolute" height="0.38in" left="4.82in" text-align="right" top="0in" width="2.63in" overflow="hidden">
                                    <fo:block>
                                        <fo:inline font-weight="bold">
                                            <xsl:text>Page: </xsl:text>
                                        </fo:inline>
                                        <fo:page-number font-weight="bold"/>
                                        <fo:inline font-weight="bold">
                                            <xsl:text> of </xsl:text>
                                        </fo:inline>
                                        <fo:page-number-citation ref-id="SV_RefID_PageTotal" font-weight="bold"/>
                                    </fo:block>
                                </fo:block-container>
                            </fo:block-container>
                        </fo:block>
                    </fo:block-container>
                </fo:static-content>
                <fo:static-content flow-name="even-page-footer">
                    <fo:block-container height="0.45in" overflow="hidden" display-align="after">
                        <fo:block>
                            <fo:block-container font-family="Arial" font-size="10pt" width="7.490000in" height="0.500000in" overflow="hidden">
                                <fo:block-container absolute-position="absolute" height="0.40in" left="0in" top="0in" width="4.04in" overflow="hidden">
                                    <fo:block>
                                        <fo:inline>
                                            <xsl:text>My Test Form</xsl:text>
                                        </fo:inline>
                                        <fo:block/>
                                        <fo:inline>
                                            <xsl:text>Test Text</xsl:text>
                                        </fo:inline>
                                    </fo:block>
                                </fo:block-container>
                                <fo:block-container absolute-position="absolute" height="0.38in" left="4.82in" text-align="right" top="0in" width="2.63in" overflow="hidden">
                                    <fo:block>
                                        <fo:inline font-weight="bold">
                                            <xsl:text>Page: </xsl:text>
                                        </fo:inline>
                                        <fo:page-number font-weight="bold"/>
                                        <fo:inline font-weight="bold">
                                            <xsl:text> of </xsl:text>
                                        </fo:inline>
                                        <fo:page-number-citation ref-id="SV_RefID_PageTotal" font-weight="bold"/>
                                    </fo:block>
                                </fo:block-container>
                            </fo:block-container>
                        </fo:block>
                    </fo:block-container>
                </fo:static-content>
                <fo:flow flow-name="xsl-region-body">
                    <fo:block>
                        <xsl:for-each select="$XML">
                            <xsl:for-each select="DOCUMENT">
                                <xsl:for-each select="DATA">
                                    <xsl:for-each select="STRUCT">
                                        <fo:block-container font-family="Arial" font-size="10pt" width="7.500000in" height="7.040000in" overflow="hidden">
                                            <fo:block-container absolute-position="absolute" font-family="Arial" font-size="13pt" font-weight="bold" height="0.28in" left="0in" text-align="center" top="0in" width="7.46in" overflow="hidden">
                                                <fo:block>
                                                    <fo:inline>
                                                        <xsl:text>Form Body Starts Here </xsl:text>
                                                    </fo:inline>
                                                    <xsl:for-each select="FIELD[FNAME=&apos;nfFormTitle&apos;]">
                                                        <xsl:for-each select="VALUE">
                                                            <xsl:variable name="value-of-template_28">
                                                                <xsl:apply-templates/>
                                                            </xsl:variable>
                                                            <xsl:choose>
                                                                <xsl:when test="contains(string($value-of-template_28),'&#x200B;')">
                                                                    <fo:block>
                                                                        <xsl:copy-of select="$value-of-template_28"/>
                                                                    </fo:block>
                                                                </xsl:when>
                                                                <xsl:otherwise>
                                                                    <fo:inline>
                                                                        <xsl:copy-of select="$value-of-template_28"/>
                                                                    </fo:inline>
                                                                </xsl:otherwise>
                                                            </xsl:choose>
                                                        </xsl:for-each>
                                                    </xsl:for-each>
                                                    <fo:inline>
                                                        <xsl:text> Test Test</xsl:text>
                                                    </fo:inline>
                                                </fo:block>
                                            </fo:block-container>

                                        </fo:block-container>
                                    </xsl:for-each>
                                </xsl:for-each>
                            </xsl:for-each>
                        </xsl:for-each>

                    </fo:block>
                    <fo:block id="SV_RefID_PageTotal"/>
                </fo:flow>
            </fo:page-sequence>
        </fo:root>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template name="altova:double-backslash">
        <xsl:param name="text"/>
        <xsl:param name="text-length"/>
        <xsl:variable name="text-after-bs" select="substring-after($text, '\')"/>
        <xsl:variable name="text-after-bs-length" select="string-length($text-after-bs)"/>
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="$text-after-bs-length = 0">
                <xsl:choose>
                    <xsl:when test="substring($text, $text-length) = '\'">
                        <xsl:value-of select="concat(substring($text,1,$text-length - 1), '\\')"/>
                    </xsl:when>
                    <xsl:otherwise>
                        <xsl:value-of select="$text"/>
                    </xsl:otherwise>
                </xsl:choose>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <xsl:value-of select="concat(substring($text,1,$text-length - $text-after-bs-length - 1), '\\')"/>
                <xsl:call-template name="altova:double-backslash">
                    <xsl:with-param name="text" select="$text-after-bs"/>
                    <xsl:with-param name="text-length" select="$text-after-bs-length"/>
                </xsl:call-template>
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template name="altova:MakeValueAbsoluteIfPixels">
        <xsl:param name="sValue"/>
        <xsl:variable name="sBeforePx" select="substring-before($sValue, 'px')"/>
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="$sBeforePx">
                <xsl:variable name="nLengthOfInteger">
                    <xsl:call-template name="altova:GetCharCountOfIntegerAtEndOfString">
                        <xsl:with-param name="sText" select="$sBeforePx"/>
                    </xsl:call-template>
                </xsl:variable>
                <xsl:variable name="nPosOfInteger" select="string-length($sBeforePx) - $nLengthOfInteger + 1"/>
                <xsl:variable name="nValuePx" select="substring($sBeforePx, $nPosOfInteger)"/>
                <xsl:variable name="nValueIn" select="number($nValuePx) div number($altova:nPxPerIn)"/>
                <xsl:variable name="nLengthBeforeInteger" select="string-length($sBeforePx) - $nLengthOfInteger"/>
                <xsl:variable name="sRest">
                    <xsl:call-template name="altova:MakeValueAbsoluteIfPixels">
                        <xsl:with-param name="sValue" select="substring-after($sValue, 'px')"/>
                    </xsl:call-template>
                </xsl:variable>
                <xsl:value-of select="concat(substring($sBeforePx, 1, $nLengthBeforeInteger), string($nValueIn), 'in', $sRest)"/>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <xsl:value-of select="$sValue"/>
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template name="altova:GetCharCountOfIntegerAtEndOfString">
        <xsl:param name="sText"/>
        <xsl:variable name="sLen" select="string-length($sText)"/>
        <xsl:variable name="cLast" select="substring($sText, $sLen)"/>
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="number($cLast) &gt;= 0 and number($cLast) &lt;= 9">
                <xsl:variable name="nResultOfRest">
                    <xsl:call-template name="altova:GetCharCountOfIntegerAtEndOfString">
                        <xsl:with-param name="sText" select="substring($sText, 1, $sLen - 1)"/>
                    </xsl:call-template>
                </xsl:variable>
                <xsl:value-of select="$nResultOfRest + 1"/>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <xsl:text>0</xsl:text>
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Does anyone know why this is happening?
I have multiple PDFs with the same layout, so if I need to upgrade to fop-2.3 do I have to make this change to all of my PDFs?

**EDIT- 1. Thank you for the comments and the answer. Sorry it took a while to reply back, as I was working on getting approvals to post this xslt.**

**2. I edited the xslt as it was too big to adhere to the word limit of this post. But it still has all the important parts like beginning of the PDF body etc.**

[image: XSLT Screenshot]

Comment: You probably have some keep conditions that were not supported in old version and now are. These kept enough content together so that it did not fit. You should post some of the FO in the flow.

Comment: It's difficult to provide an answer without a [_minimal, complete and verifiable example_](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (= a small FO file showing the problem you are experiencing, in this case). Be sure to edit it into your question by copying and pasting the *text*, rather than adding a *screenshot* of it, otherwise people will have to type it again in order to use it.

Comment: @KevinBrown Thank you for the comment. I've posted most parts of the huge XSLT to adhere to the word limit.

Comment: @lfurini Thank you for the comment and helping me learn how to improve my question.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, but the best way to work out why something is different between different versions of the same software is to look through the release notes for the releases since your older version.

FOP has release notes on its website.  When I was confirming that, I found this at https://xmlgraphics.apache.org/fop/1.0/changes_1.0.html, which might be what you are looking for:

> Allowing non-zero borders and padding on page regions when relaxed validation is turned on. Committed by LF.

If that is the cause, then the solution would be to remove the `margin-top` from the `fo:simple-page-master`.  Otherwise, there's plenty more release notes for you to look through, I'm afraid.

Comment: Hi Tony, thank you for the answer. Looking through the release notes is the first thing I started doing but I must go through all the releases from 1.0 to 2.3 which I am doing, I just thought what if it was something simple that I was missing out, I could post this question and get an answer while going through the notes. I haven't found anything that could classify as the answer, but I’m trying.

Comment: Good luck!  I am not a FOP expert, otherwise I might have been able to help you more.